# How do you manage the visible input fields accepted in an API HttpPost request?

Tags: api, .net-core

In my API I have a Create method in my controller that accepts all of the models fields, but in the method I'm excluding the ID field since on a create it's generated.  But in Swagger it's showing the following.

[image]

Is there a way for it not to show the following part?

"id": 0

Is a viewmodel how I should go about this?

I tried the following, but can't get it to work.

```
public class PartVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IPartService
{
    Task<Part> CreatePart(PartVM part);
    Task<IEnumerable<Part>> GetParts();
    Task<Part> GetPart(int partId);
}

public class PartService : IPartService
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;

    public PartService(AppDbContext appDbContext)
    {
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }

    public async Task<Part> CreatePart(PartVM part)
    {
        var _part = new Part()
        {
            Name = part.Name
        };

        var result = await _appDbContext.Parts.AddAsync(_part);
        await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return result.Entity;
    }
 }
```

Here's my controller.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PartsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IPartService _partService;

    public PartsController(IPartService partService)
    {
        _partService = partService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Part>> CreatePart(PartVM part)
    {
        try
        {
            if (part == null)
                return BadRequest();

            var _part = new Part()
            {
                Name = part.Name
            };

            var createdPart = await _partService.CreatePart(_part);

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetPart),
                new { id = createdPart.Id}, createdPart);
        }
        catch (Exception /*ex*/)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Error creating new record in the database");
        }
    }
```

I'm getting a build error saying "CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MusicManager.Shared.Part' to 'MusicManager.Server.Data.ViewModels.PartVM'".

It's refering to "_part" in this line "var createdPart = await _partService.CreatePart(_part);".

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you have a `CreatePart` method which receives a `PartVM` model, but you are sending a `Part` Model to it

change your method to this :

```
public async Task<Part> CreatePart(Part part)
{
    var result = await _appDbContext.Parts.AddAsync(_part);
    await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return result.Entity;
}
```